# Need to Query Google Sheet for specific data from Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a web app to track the working hours of employees at my company, the web app is simple, it first asks them to provide their username and a password, and then allows them to register their time of entry o their exit time. My boss has also asked me if there is a way that employees can see what their last 3 registrations were, in case they may have forgotten to record an entry or exit time. So what I need to do is look for each employee's specific name/id in the sheet where the data is being received, and print that data on the web app under a "Last Registrations" section.

Here is a minimal reproducible example, that just asks for a name, looks for that name in a data base and then allows you to send your submission while bringing the timestamp of the submission. All i would need to see is how to look for the person's name in the data base of "ReceivedData" (which comes from earlier registrations on the the web app) and how to bring the timestamp from that submission to the web app under the "Last Registrations section". Here is also a spreadsheet with some data where you can work.
(https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CJoPuq3sHE5L31GwlvS4Zygm1sL3M0HGC7MgW3rCq3g/edit#gid=0)

Sorry for the long description and thank you.

```js
var name="";

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Form');
}
function AddRecord(Name) {
  
  // get spreadsheet details
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CJoPuq3sHE5L31GwlvS4Zygm1sL3M0HGC7MgW3rCq3g/edit#gid=0';
  //Paste URL of GOOGLE SHEET
  var ss1= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet1 = ss1.getActiveSheet();
  const Lrow = webAppSheet1.getLastRow();
  const data = [Name, new Date ()];

  webAppSheet1.getRange(Lrow+1,1, 1, data.length).setValues([data])       
}

function checkLogin(Name) {
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CJoPuq3sHE5L31GwlvS4Zygm1sL3M0HGC7MgW3rCq3g/edit#gid=0';
  //Paste URL of GOOGLE SHEET
  var ss2= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("DataBase");
  var getLastRow =  webAppSheet2.getLastRow();
  var found_record = '';
  for(var i = 1; i <= getLastRow; i++)
  {
   if(webAppSheet2.getRange(i, 1).getValue() == Name)
   {
     found_record = 'TRUE';
   }    
  }
  if(found_record == '')
  {
    found_record = 'FALSE'; 
  }
  
  return found_record;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
    function AddRow()
    {
      var Name = document.getElementById("Name").value;  
      google.script.run.AddRecord(Name);
      document.getElementById("Name").value = '';
      }    
          function LoginUser()
    {
    var Name = document.getElementById("Name").value;
    
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(output) 
    {
      if(output == 'TRUE')
      {
        document.getElementById("loginDisplay").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("dataDisplay").style.display = "block";     
      }
      else if(output == 'FALSE')
      {
        document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Name not found";     
      }    
    }).checkLogin(Name);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="loginDisplay">
    <div> 
    <label>Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="Name" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="btn">
<input value="Login" onclick="LoginUser()"
 type="button">
 <span id="errorMessage"></span>
</div> 

    </div>
    <div style="display:none"  id="dataDisplay">
    <div>
    <label>Last Registrations</label>
    <br><br>
    <button type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddRow()">Send</button>
</div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to provide public access on your link

Comment: Sorry, i had forgotten to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- From `So what I need to do is look for each employee's specific name/id in the sheet where the data is being received, and print that data on the web app under a "Last Registrations" section.` and `All i would need to see is how to look for the person's name in the data base of "ReceivedData" (which comes from earlier registrations on the the web app) and how to bring the timestamp from that submission to the web app under the "Last Registrations section".`, I understood your question as follows.

  1. You want to search the inputted value from `ReceivedData` sheet in the Spreadsheet.
  2. You want to put the last timestamp retrieved by searching the inputted value from the sheet to below of "Last Registrations section".

### Modification points:

- From your script, I thought that when the script for searching the inputted value is included in the function `checkLogin` in GAS side, it might be suitable.
- And, in order to show the last timestamp, `<div id="lastTimestamp"></div>` is added to HTML and `LoginUser` in Javascript is modified.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

#### Google Apps Script side:

Please modify `checkLogin` as follows.

```
function checkLogin(Name) {
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CJoPuq3sHE5L31GwlvS4Zygm1sL3M0HGC7MgW3rCq3g/edit#gid=0'; //Paste URL of GOOGLE SHEET
  var ss2= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("DataBase");
  var check = webAppSheet2.getRange(2, 1, webAppSheet2.getLastRow(), 1).createTextFinder(Name).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
  var obj = {check: check ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'};
  var sheet = ss2.getSheetByName("ReceivedData");
  var ranges = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).createTextFinder(Name).matchEntireCell(true).findAll();
  if (ranges.length > 0) {
    obj.lastTimestamp = ranges.pop().offset(0, 1, 1, 1).getDisplayValue();
    return obj;
  }
  return obj;
}
```

#### HTML & Javascript side:

Please modify `LoginUser` as follows.

```
function LoginUser() {
  var Name = document.getElementById("Name").value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function({check, lastTimestamp}) {
    if(check == 'TRUE') {
      document.getElementById("loginDisplay").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("dataDisplay").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("lastTimestamp").innerHTML = lastTimestamp;
    } else if(check == 'FALSE') {
      document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Name not found";
    }
  }).checkLogin(Name);
}
```

And, please add HTML as follows.

From:

```
<label>Last Registrations</label>
<br><br>
<button type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddRow()">Send</button>
```

To:

```
<label>Last Registrations</label>
<br><br>
<div id="lastTimestamp"></div>
<button type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddRow()">Send</button>
```

### Note:

- In this modified script, your shared Spreadsheet and script are used. So when the structure of Spreadsheet is changed, the script might not be able to be used. Please be careful this.

### Reference:

- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work perfectly! But do you know how i can adapt this to check for a username and a password (and make sure that this coincide), instead of just a name?

Comment: @Sebastian Carrasco Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. Unfortunately, I cannot have the clear vision of your new question and that is different from your question. I apologize for this. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Here is the link to the new question I have added. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65773045/need-to-check-for-login-username-and-password-and-then-bring-data-from-previous

Comment: I think the solution is similar to this question, but the only difference is that instead of just looking for the employee's name in the "DataBase" sheet, the "CheckLogin" function has to also search for the password and make sure it matches the name of the employee.

Comment: @Sebastian Carrasco Thank you for your response. I saw your new question and posted an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Hello, I have already confirmed your answer to my previous question, sorry for taking so long. I have a new question involving the same web app, if you could please help me with it, I would appreciate it very much. Here is the link to the new question (stackoverflow.com/questions/65983933/…).