# Need to check for login username and password, and then bring data from previous entries

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Following this question I had asked previously ([Need to Query Google Sheet for specific data from Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65717284/need-to-query-google-sheet-for-specific-data-from-google-apps-script)).

I have created a web app to track the working hours of employees at my company, the web app is simple, it first asks them to provide their username and a password, and then allows them to register their time of entry o their exit time. Now, I need to find a way to check for a match between username and password (in a data base), and if this is true, bring information about that employee's last submission to the web app, this last submission data is found on another sheet that receives the data from the web app.

Here is a minimal reproducible example, where its just asks for a name and a password, and if correct, show another display, where it brings the timestamp of that user's last submission to the web app.

```js
var name="";

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Form');
}
function AddRecord(Name) {
  
  // get spreadsheet details
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CJoPuq3sHE5L31GwlvS4Zygm1sL3M0HGC7MgW3rCq3g/edit#gid=0';
  //Paste URL of GOOGLE SHEET
  var ss1= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet1 = ss1.getActiveSheet();
  const Lrow = webAppSheet1.getLastRow();
  const data = [Name, new Date ()];

  webAppSheet1.getRange(Lrow+1,1, 1, data.length).setValues([data])       
}

function checklogin(Name,Password) {
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CJoPuq3sHE5L31GwlvS4Zygm1sL3M0HGC7MgW3rCq3g/edit#gid=0'; //Paste URL of GOOGLE SHEET
  var ss2= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("DataBase");
  var checkuser = webAppSheet2.getRange(2, 1, webAppSheet2.getLastRow(), 1).createTextFinder(Name).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
  var obj = {checkuser: checkuser ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'};
  var sheet = ss2.getSheetByName("ReceivedData");
  var ranges = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).createTextFinder(Name).matchEntireCell(true).findAll();
  if (ranges.length > 0) {
    obj.lastTimestamp = ranges.pop().offset(0, 1, 1, 1).getDisplayValue();
    return obj;
  }
  return obj;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
    #LastR{
    display: inline-block;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    function AddRow()
    {
      var Name = document.getElementById("Name").value;  
      google.script.run.AddRecord(Name);
      document.getElementById("Name").value = '';
      }    
function LoginUser() {
  var Name = document.getElementById("Name").value;
  var Password = document.getElementById("Password").value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function({checkuser, lastTimestamp}) {
    if(checkuser == 'TRUE') {
      document.getElementById("loginDisplay").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("dataDisplay").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("lastTimestamp").innerHTML = lastTimestamp;
    } else if(checkuser == 'FALSE') {
      document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Name not found";
    }
  }).checklogin(Name,Password);
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="loginDisplay">
    <div> 
    <label>Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="Name" />
    </div>
        <div> 
    <label>Password</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="Password" />
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
<input value="Login" onclick="LoginUser()"
 type="button">
 <span id="errorMessage"></span>
</div> 

    </div>
    <div style="display:none"  id="dataDisplay">
    <div>
<label>Last Registration</label>
<br><br>
<div class="LastR" id="lastTimestamp"></div>
<button type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddRow()">Send</button>
</div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is a sheet where you can work from or copy the information.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CJoPuq3sHE5L31GwlvS4Zygm1sL3M0HGC7MgW3rCq3g/edit#gid=0

Comment: The real problem with doing this is maintaining the state of the login authentication from one get to the next.  In websites built on technologies like asp and php they use cookies to maintain session state and you could do that but most people don't and so it's not easy to guarantee that the person that just login on the last get is really that same person.  It would  probably be better in a situation like this to have all your employees on the same domain or perhaps even use a Google Login.  All of this may not be  necessary for you if ou don't care about your employees privacy.

Comment: If you were to try to compel me to use such a system for my work.  I may end up sueing you and most certainly would probably not use it.  It may be cheap and easy  to use apps script in this situation. However, it may not be wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to search the inputted values of `Name` and `Password` from `DataBase` sheet in the Spreadsheet.
- You want to show the last timestamp retrieved from `ReceivedData` sheet by searching the inputted values from `DataBase` sheet.

In this case, I would like to propose to modify `var obj = {checkuser: checkuser ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'};` of the function `checklogin` for achieving your goal as follows.

#### From:

```
var obj = {checkuser: checkuser ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'};
```

#### To:

```
var obj = {checkuser: checkuser && checkuser.offset(0, 1).getValue() == Password ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'};
```

- In this modification, the inputted `Name` value is searched from the 1st column, and then, `Password` is checked from the 2nd column with the same row of the searched 1st column. And, when the both values are same, `TRUE` is returned.

#### Reference:

- [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset)