# Check for login username and password, and then bring data from every previous entry

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Similar to a question I had asked previously ([Need to check for login username and password, and then bring data from previous entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65773045/need-to-check-for-login-username-and-password-and-then-bring-data-from-previous)).

I have created a web app to track the working hours of employees at my company, the web app is simple, it first asks them to provide their username and a password, and then allows them to register their time of entry o their exit time. Now, I need to find a way to check for a match between username and password (in a data base), and if this is true, bring information about all of the previous submissions that employee has made to the web app, these previous entries are found on a google sheet that receives the data from the web app.

Here is a minimal reproducible example, where its just asks for a name and a password, and if true, show another display, where it first asks for a date and time of entry and then it only brings that employee's last submission to the web app, but I now need for to bring every previous entry that employee has made.

```js
var name="";

function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Form');
}
function AddRecord(Name, Date, Time) {
  
  // get spreadsheet details
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CJoPuq3sHE5L31GwlvS4Zygm1sL3M0HGC7MgW3rCq3g/edit#gid=0';
  //Paste URL of GOOGLE SHEET
  var ss1= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet1 = ss1.getActiveSheet();
  const Lrow = webAppSheet1.getLastRow();
  const data = [Name, Date, Time];

  webAppSheet1.getRange(Lrow+1,1, 1, data.length).setValues([data])       
}

function checklogin(Name,Password) {
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CJoPuq3sHE5L31GwlvS4Zygm1sL3M0HGC7MgW3rCq3g/edit#gid=0'; //Paste URL of GOOGLE SHEET
  var ss2= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("DataBase");
  var checkuser = webAppSheet2.getRange(2, 1, webAppSheet2.getLastRow(), 1).createTextFinder(Name).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
  var obj = {checkuser: checkuser && checkuser.offset(0, 1).getValue() == Password ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'};
  var sheet = ss2.getSheetByName("ReceivedData");
  var ranges = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).createTextFinder(Name).matchEntireCell(true).findAll();
  if (ranges.length > 0) {
  var last = ranges.pop();
    obj.lastDate = last.offset(0, 1, 1, 1).getDisplayValue();
    obj.lastTime = last.offset(0, 2, 1, 1).getDisplayValue();
    return obj;
  }
  return obj;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
    </style>
    <script>
    function AddRow()
    {
      var Name = document.getElementById("Name").value;  
      var Date = document.getElementById("Date").value; 
      var Time = document.getElementById("Time").value;
      google.script.run.AddRecord(Name, Date, Time);
      document.getElementById("Name").value = '';
      document.getElementById("Date").value = '';
      document.getElementById("Time").value = '';
      }    
function LoginUser() {
  var Name = document.getElementById("Name").value;
  var Password = document.getElementById("Password").value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function({checkuser, lastTime, lastDate}) {
    if(checkuser == 'TRUE') {
      document.getElementById("loginDisplay").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("dataDisplay").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("lastTime").innerHTML = lastTime;
      document.getElementById("lastDate").innerHTML = lastDate;
    } else if(checkuser == 'FALSE') {
      document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Name not found";
    }
  }).checklogin(Name,Password);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="loginDisplay">
    
    <div>
      <label>Name</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="Name" />
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <label>Password</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="Password" />
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <input value="Login" onclick="LoginUser()"type="button">
        <span id="errorMessage"></span>
    </div>
    
</div> 
    
<div style="display:none"  id="dataDisplay">

  <div>
    <label>Date</label><br>
    <input type="date" id="Date" />  
  </div>
  
  <div>  
    <label>Time</label><br>
    <input type="time" id="Time" />
  </div>
    
  <div>  
    <button type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddRow()">Send</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <br><label>Last Registration</label><br>
    <span id="lastTime"></span> || <span id="lastDate"></span>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is a sheet where you can work from or copy the information. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CJoPuq3sHE5L31GwlvS4Zygm1sL3M0HGC7MgW3rCq3g/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- When `Name` and `Password` are given to the function of `checklogin`, you want to retrieve all matched values.

### Modification points:

- In this case, I thought that the following part in your Google Apps Script side is required to be modified.

  ```
    var last = ranges.pop();
    obj.lastDate = last.offset(0, 1, 1, 1).getDisplayValue();
    obj.lastTime = last.offset(0, 2, 1, 1).getDisplayValue();
  ```
- And, in this case, `offset(0, 1, 1, 2)` is used, 2 columns can be retrieved by one call.
- When you want to display the time and date like `time || date`, it is required to modify your HTML and Javascript.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

#### Google Apps Script side:

Please modify the function `checklogin` as follows.

From:

```
var last = ranges.pop();
  obj.lastDate = last.offset(0, 1, 1, 1).getDisplayValue();
  obj.lastTime = last.offset(0, 2, 1, 1).getDisplayValue();
```

To:

```
obj.dateTime = ranges.flatMap(r => r.offset(0, 1, 1, 2).getDisplayValues());
```

#### HTML&Javascript side.

From:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function({checkuser, lastTime, lastDate}) {
  if(checkuser == 'TRUE') {
    document.getElementById("loginDisplay").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("dataDisplay").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("lastTime").innerHTML = lastTime;
    document.getElementById("lastDate").innerHTML = lastDate;
  } else if(checkuser == 'FALSE') {
    document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Name not found";
  }
}).checklogin(Name,Password);
```

To:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function({checkuser, dateTime}) {
  if(checkuser == 'TRUE') {
    document.getElementById("loginDisplay").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("dataDisplay").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("dateTime").innerHTML = dateTime.map(([a, b]) => `${b} || ${a}`).join("<br>");
  } else if(checkuser == 'FALSE') {
    document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Name not found";
  }
}).checklogin(Name,Password);
```

And

From:

```
<span id="lastTime"></span> || <span id="lastDate"></span>
```

To:

```
<span id="dateTime"></span>
```

### Note:

- From your question, unfortunately, I cannot understand about the situation of your actual goal. So in above modified script, I followed your current display. So please modify this for your actual goal.

### References:

- [offset(rowOffset, columnOffset, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)

Comment: My goal for this question is to bring every previous entry that employee has submitted to the web app, instead of just only bringing the single last registration they  made

Comment: @Sebastian Carrasco Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your replying, I think that my proposed script works for it. In my proposed modified script, all values by searching `Name` and `Password` are retrieved. So I cannot understand whether my understanding for your question is correct. I apologize for this again. In order to correctly understand about your goal, Can you provide the sample output you expect using your shared Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to try to understand it, and if my understanding is not correct, I would like to modify it.

Comment: The problem is after making the changes you have told me to make in the answer, it doesn't work. It doesn't let me login, so I can't see if the last registrations have been brought correctly. Can you please check if there is any other modification you may have forgot to include in the answer?

Comment: Hello, I have added a new question similar to this one, can you please take a look at it to see if you can help me? Here is the link to the question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66424885/need-to-retrieve-a-specific-amount-of-data-from-prvious-entries-on-gas-web-app).