# Need to retrieve a specific amount of data from previous entries on GAS web app

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Similar to a question I had asked previously ([Check for login username and password, and then bring data from every previous entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65983933/check-for-login-username-and-password-and-then-bring-data-from-every-previous-e)).

I have created a web app to track the working hours of employees at my company, the web app is simple, it first asks them to provide their username and a password, and then allows them to register their time of entry o their exit time. Now, I need to find a way to check for a match between username and password (in a data base), and if this is true, bring information about the **last 10 previous entries** that employee has made to the web app, instead of retrieving all of the these previous entries that employee has made, the data about previous entries is found on a google sheet that receives the data from the web app.

Here is a minimal reproducible example, where its just asks for a name and a password, and if true, show another display, where it first asks for a date and time of entry and then it every previous entry that person has made, **but I now need for it to bring the last 10 entries that employee has made**.

```js
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Form');
}
function AddRecord(Name, Date, Time) {
  
  // get spreadsheet details
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CJoPuq3sHE5L31GwlvS4Zygm1sL3M0HGC7MgW3rCq3g/edit#gid=0';
  //Paste URL of GOOGLE SHEET
  var ss1= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet1 = ss1.getActiveSheet();
  const Lrow = webAppSheet1.getLastRow();
  const data = [Name, Date, Time];

  webAppSheet1.getRange(Lrow+1,1, 1, data.length).setValues([data])       
}

function checklogin(Name,Password) {
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CJoPuq3sHE5L31GwlvS4Zygm1sL3M0HGC7MgW3rCq3g/edit#gid=0'; //Paste URL of GOOGLE SHEET
  var ss2= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var webAppSheet2 = ss2.getSheetByName("DataBase");
  var checkuser = webAppSheet2.getRange(2, 1, webAppSheet2.getLastRow(), 1).createTextFinder(Name).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
  var obj = {checkuser: checkuser && checkuser.offset(0, 1).getValue() == Password ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE'};
  var sheet = ss2.getSheetByName("ReceivedData");
  var ranges = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).createTextFinder(Name).matchEntireCell(true).findAll();
  if (ranges.length > 0) {
obj.dateTime = ranges.flatMap(r => r.offset(0, 1, 1, 2).getDisplayValues());
    return obj;
  }
  return obj;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
    </style>
    <script>
    function AddRow()
    {
      var Name = document.getElementById("Name").value;  
      var Date = document.getElementById("Date").value; 
      var Time = document.getElementById("Time").value;
      google.script.run.AddRecord(Name, Date, Time);
      document.getElementById("Name").value = '';
      document.getElementById("Date").value = '';
      document.getElementById("Time").value = '';
      }    
function LoginUser() {
  var Name = document.getElementById("Name").value;
  var Password = document.getElementById("Password").value;
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function({checkuser, dateTime}) {
  if(checkuser == 'TRUE') {
    document.getElementById("loginDisplay").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("dataDisplay").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("dateTime").innerHTML = dateTime.map(([a, b]) => `${b} || ${a}`).join("<br>");
  } else if(checkuser == 'FALSE') {
    document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Name not found";
  }
}).checklogin(Name,Password);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="loginDisplay">
    
    <div>
      <label>Name</label><br>
      <input type="text" id="Name" />
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <label>Password</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="Password" />
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <input value="Login" onclick="LoginUser()"type="button">
        <span id="errorMessage"></span>
    </div>
    
</div> 
    
<div style="display:none"  id="dataDisplay">

  <div>
    <label>Date</label><br>
    <input type="date" id="Date" />  
  </div>
  
  <div>  
    <label>Time</label><br>
    <input type="time" id="Time" />
  </div>
    
  <div>  
    <button type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddRow()">Send</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <br><label>Last Registration</label><br>
    <span id="dateTime"></span>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is a sheet where you can work from or copy the information. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CJoPuq3sHE5L31GwlvS4Zygm1sL3M0HGC7MgW3rCq3g/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve 10 values from the function `checklogin()`.
- The rows of your Spreadsheet is the scending order.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
if (ranges.length > 0) {
  obj.dateTime = ranges.flatMap(r => r.offset(0, 1, 1, 2).getDisplayValues());
  return obj;
}
```

#### To:

```
if (ranges.length > 0) {
  if (ranges.length > 10) {
    ranges = ranges.splice(-10);
  }
  obj.date1Time = ranges.flatMap(r => r.offset(0, 1, 1, 2).getDisplayValues());
  return obj;
}
```

- By this modification, when the length of `ranges` is over 10, the last 10 values are retrieved.
- When the length of `ranges` is NOT over 10, all values are retrieved.
- If you want to sort as the descending order and you want to retrieve first 10 values, please modify `ranges = ranges.splice(-10)` to `ranges = ranges.splice(0, 10)`.

#### Reference:

- [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)